# JQ Sorting by value

Tags: bash, jq

I am looking to sort an array in JQ by a custom map of values and struggling to figure it out. Hoping someone here can point out a way to do this.

I have an array of objects that describe software vulnerabilities and want to sort the objects in order by Severity value: CRITICAL, HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW

The array looks like this:

```
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "MEDIUM",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "CRITICAL",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "LOW",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there an easy-ish way to do this with JQ?

Thank you!

I have tried using the sort_by() function in JQ but can't seem to figure out how to apply a custom order (not looking to organize alphabetically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a stream of booleans, and sort by that. (Use `!=` for the same order, `==` for reversed order.)

```bash
.vulnerabilities |= sort_by(.Severity != ("CRITICAL","HIGH","MEDIUM","LOW"))
```

```json
{
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "CRITICAL",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "HIGH",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "MEDIUM",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    },
    {
      "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
      "Product": "ncurses-base",
      "Severity": "LOW",
      "Version": "6.3-2",
      "Description": "example"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XPs3Yh9RUc3)

Comment: Edit, this one works with quite a few items from my testing

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Independently, for each item in the `.vulnerabilities` array, this creates a stream of four booleans, one for each kind of severity, and in the order provided. `sort_by` will then turn this into a four-element array, and sort the item in question accordingly. So, the order of items within the same group of severities is undefined (but will probably be in the original order) but the groups themselves will be sorted according to the boolean array (with `false < true`).

Answer (score 2):

Create a map from strings to numbers; look up the strings and sort by the resulting numbers.

```
{ "CRITICAL": 0, "HIGH": 1, "MEDIUM": 2, "LOW": 3} as $priority_orders |
.vulnerabilities | sort_by($priority_orders[.Severity])
```

...properly returns, given your input data:

```json
[
  {
    "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
    "Product": "ncurses-base",
    "Severity": "CRITICAL",
    "Version": "6.3-2",
    "Description": "example"
  },
  {
    "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
    "Product": "ncurses-base",
    "Severity": "HIGH",
    "Version": "6.3-2",
    "Description": "example"
  },
  {
    "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
    "Product": "ncurses-base",
    "Severity": "MEDIUM",
    "Version": "6.3-2",
    "Description": "example"
  },
  {
    "CVEID": "CVE-2022-29458",
    "Product": "ncurses-base",
    "Severity": "LOW",
    "Version": "6.3-2",
    "Description": "example"
  }
]
```

(You might want to instead sort by a list or tuple, such as `[$priority_orders[.Severity], .Product, .Version]`, to come up with data that's usefully ordered when there's more than one thing at each severity level; consider it left as an exercise to the reader).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Both posted solutions work like a charm